# Calling a method in an angular Component from an external JS file

Tags: angular, scorm

I am developing an e-learning application that plays SCORM content. I'm fairly new to angular and scorm. I'm using angular 4 and spring boot. I am facing difficulty in exposing the backend API to the SCORM content.

These are what I have tried so far:

The below code view-course-content.ts has all the 8 SCORM methods that the SCO will invoke from a javascript file inorder to communicate with the LMS.

view-course-content.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import { LaunchService } from '../services/launch-service.service';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
//import { IndexComponent } from './../index/index.component'




@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-course-content',
  templateUrl: './view-course-content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-course-content.component.css']
})
export class ViewCourseContentComponent implements OnInit {

  pdfUrl;
  courseId;
  API;
  formData = new FormData();
  pdfSrc;
  api = 'http://localhost:8080';



  @ViewChild('API_1484_11') API_NN;
  @ViewChild('API') API_IE;
   @ViewChild('APIHOLDER') APIHOLDER;

  debug = true;




 constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private dataService: DataService, private launchService: LaunchService, private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private apiService : ApiService,private elementRef: ElementRef) {
   console.log('Unit Id in viewCourse', this.dataService.unitId);  
  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
       this.courseId = params['id'];
      this.formData.append('courseId', params['id']);
      console.log(this.courseId);
    });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.scormAPI = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/js/api.js');


  }


//------------------------------------------
//SCORM RTE Functions - Initialization
//------------------------------------------
Initialize(dummyString) { 
  console.log("Inside Initialize() function");
if (this.debug) { alert('*** LMSInitialize ***'); }
console.log("Inside Initialize() function");
//return this.API_1484_11.Initialize();
// return "true";

this.apiService.initialize().subscribe((response) => {
      console.log('Inside apiService Initialize call in view-course-component-ts ');
     // console.log("Response inside view course content", response['_body']);
})

}

//------------------------------------------
//SCORM RTE Functions - Getting and Setting Values
//------------------------------------------
GetValue(varname) {
if (this.debug) { 
 alert('*** LMSGetValue varname='+varname
                       +' varvalue=value ***');
}


}

LMSSetValue(varname,varvalue) {
if (this.debug) { 
 alert('*** LMSSetValue varname='+varname
                       +' varvalue='+varvalue+' ***');
}
}

 LMSCommit(dummyString) {
if (this.debug) { alert('*** LMSCommit ***'); }
return "true";
}

//------------------------------------------
//SCORM RTE Functions - Closing The Session
//------------------------------------------
LMSFinish(dummyString) {
if (this.debug) { alert('*** LMSFinish ***'); }
return "true";
}

//------------------------------------------
//SCORM RTE Functions - Error Handling
//------------------------------------------
LMSGetLastError() {
if (this.debug) { alert('*** LMSGetLastError ***'); }
return 0;
}

LMSGetDiagnostic(errorCode) {
if (this.debug) { 
 alert('*** LMSGetDiagnostic errorCode='+errorCode+' ***');
}
return "diagnostic string";
}

LMSGetErrorString(errorCode) {
if (this.debug) { 
 alert('*** LMSGetErrorString errorCode='+errorCode+' ***'); 
}
return "error string";
}
```

}

The below code actually launches the SCORM content. I have put it in a frameset.

view-course-content.component.html

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="assets/runtime/BrowserDetect.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript"
    src="assets/js/SCORM_API_wrapper.js"></script>   -->
     <script type="text/javascript"
    src="assets/js/scormAPI.js"></script>
<div>  


   <div align="center"> View Course Content Page </div> 

     <div id="scormContent" *ngIf = "unitId == 2">

         <frameset frameborder="0" border="0" rows="0,*" cols="*" >


    <frame 
        src="assets/CourseImports/shared/launchpage.html"
        name="Content" id="Content" marginwidth="1px;" marginheight="1px;" noresize="noresize"></frame>



    </frameset>
```

The courses are launched from the dashboard.

dashboard.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid dashboard">
    <div class="row ">


        <h1 class="page-header page-heading animated fadeInDownBig">
            Courses<small></small>
        </h1>



        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" *ngFor='let course of courses'>

            <div class="widget widget-stats bg-aqua-lighter">
                <div class="stats-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-desktop:before"></i>
                </div>
                <a target="_blank" href="javascript:void(0);"
                    (click)="viewCourse(course.courseId)">

                    <div class="img-hover">
                        <img src="api/admin/getCourseCoverImage{{course.courseId}}"
                            id="coverImage" alt="HTML5 Image" height="70px" width="120px"
                            class="img-responsive img-rounded" />
                    </div>
                </a>

                <div class="stats-info">
                    <!-- <p id="testId_${publishedTestSurvey.testDetails.testId}">${publishedTestSurvey.testDetails.testName}</p>
                                        <h4>${fn:length(publishedTestSurvey.testDetails.testQuestionDetailsSet)}
                                            questions | ${publishedTestSurvey.testDetails.duration}
                                            Minutes | ${publishedTestSurvey.testDetails.testRepetitions}
                                            Total Attempts</h4> -->
                    <p>{{course.courseName}}</p>
                    <div class="stats-link">
                        <!-- <a target="_blank" href="view-course/{{course.courseId}}" (click)="viewCourse(course.courseId)">  
                                                Open Course <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i>
                                            </a> -->
                        <!-- <a target="_blank" href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="viewCourse(course.courseId)">  
                                                Open Course <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i>
                                            </a> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>    
</div>
```

These are the calls that the SCO will make to communicate with the LMS

```
API.Initialize()
API.SetValue()
API.GetValue()
API.Terminate()
API.GetLastError()
API.GetErrorString()
API.GetDiagnostic()
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to expose the SCORM methods in view-course-content.ts to the above js calls that the SCORM content will be making.

view-course-content.ts is my Javascript API that needs to be called. 
How can I capture the calls made by the js file and redirect it to the methods in view-course-content.component.ts? I have no control whatsoever on the js file that is making these calls.

Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: hi @Just_like_you , im trying to implement a SCORM system in an angular project too, do you mind linking to resources where i can find information about doing so? maybe even your code? thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to expose the API in the view-course-content.component.ts file in the ngOnInit function like below:

```
window["API_1484_11"] = this.api_1484_11
```

where api_1484_11 is another angular component that had all the 8 API calls implemented and injected into the view-course-content.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming API.Initialize(), etc, are all attached to `window`, you should be able to do:

```
(<any>window).API.Initialize();
```

You could put all of these calls into an angular service and then inject it in to any components that need to talk to the `API` object. Such as,
**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  initialize:string {
     return (<any>window).API.Initialize();
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private myservice: MyService) {}
   ngOnInit() {
      this.myservice.initialize();
   }
}
```

I've followed the steps in angular's tutorial to [create a service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#creating-a-hero-service) before. It seemed to work out pretty well.

Comment: @1221076,thanks for your comment. My understanding of scorm content and API interaction is that a scorm content always has a plain js and I should be able to capture the calls that the scorm content initiates from that plain js, is my understanding not right? My main issue is that I'm unable to capture the API.Initialize() call from the plain js of a sco. From your comment, I understand that we are initiating the API call from the component. But that is not how it works, the content should initialize the communication, right? Please correct me if I'm wrong.